# how to do manual search on NCBI with biopython and add link to publication

Tags: python, biopython, ncbi

I'm trying to reproduce a complex manual search on NCBI using BioPython, but obviously something is not right. My command line is not working, but I'd especially like a way to have an accurate search where I can select only the genomes related to a published paper. Is there an easy way to do that?

I want to limit my results to only those genomes that i) have an NCBI BioProject entry and ii) that BioProject entry contains a `Publications` field.

For example, let's say I want all the genomes of Microbacterium, the latest version, from RefSeq and not partial (this is what I tried to write but something is not working) and I would like to add one more filter. Take, among the remaining/selected genomes, only the ones related to published papers.

For this strain, we have a related paper:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/bioproject/PRJNA669461/

For this one, we do not:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/bioproject/PRJNA608230/

and I really would like to not have to check 100 genomes manually, but I don't know how to manage it.

I tried:

```py
query = "Microbacterium[Organism] AND latest refseq[filter] AND (all[filter] NOT
partial[filter])"
handle = Entrez.esearch(term=query, db="Assembly", retmax=600)
ids = Entrez.read(handle)["IdList"]
```

And after this, I'm just using a `for` loop to get genomes, but my query is not good and it is not handling the problem of the publication.

Thanks for any help!

---

Edit : as I need to search in the db Assembly unfortunately the answer with the flag author or date is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entrez has the tags [journal], [volume], [page number], [title], [year] and [author] to identify all sequences from a given publication. You will find a full list of tags [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/advanced) from the drop down menu.

Thus,

```
query = "Microbacterium[Organism] AND Nature[Journal] AND 528[volume] AND Bai[author] AND 364[page number]"
```

This will identify all *Microbacterium* genome sequences associated with Bai *et al* (2015) Nature 528:364- and is [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=Microbacterium%5BOrganism%5D%20AND%20NATURE%5BJournal%5D%20AND%20nature%5BJournal%5D%20AND%20528%5Bvolume%5D%20AND%20Bai%5Bauthor%5D%20AND%20364%5Bpage%20number%5D).

For practical purposes I routinely search using the organism and author tags for their sequence output.

---

The example given (post-edit) was

> Kim KK et al., "Microbacterium aquimaris sp. nov., isolated from seawater.", Int J Syst Evol Microbiol, 2008 Jul;58(Pt 7):1616-20

```
query = "Microbacterium[Organism] AND 58[volume] AND Kim[author] AND 1616[page number] AND 2008[year]"
```

I removed the [journal] tag because the abbreviation it uses is a bit unusual and replaced it with [year]. Still works [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=Microbacterium%5BOrganism%5D%20AND%2058%5Bvolume%5D%20AND%20Kim%5Bauthor%5D%20AND%201616%5Bpage%20number%5D%20AND%202008%5Byear%5D).

---

From the comments ... if only published sequences were required then using the `range` function and `[publication date]` is one way in ...

```
query = "Microbacterium[Organism] AND 2000/1/1:2020/1/1[publication date]"
```

The best strategy is to use the `[author]` because data production tends to be dominated by a small number of groups.

---

**Comments of Comments**

Why isn't searching working. The following search works

```
query = "Microbacterium[Organism] AND (all[filter] NOT partial[filter])"
```

The term it doesn't like is `latest refseq[filter]` if that is removed it will work. `refseq` works, but it doesn't like `latest`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to limit the results to only those genomes whose NCBI BioProject entry includes a `Publications` field.

Comment: @terdon I don't believe there is a tag `[publication]`, there is `[publication date]`, which is better than `[year]`. However, it's the same answer, the sequence output of most fields are represented only by a small number of authors and only those authors are searched.

Comment: @M__ thanks a lot for your help ! your range idea it's pretty clever, it will already be much better than checking by hand!

Comment: Thanks @MarineBergot please remember to "accept" if it's useful. You can always switch "accepted" posts if there's a better way posted later.

Comment: @M__ by the way, do you have any idea why my current research is not returning anything?

Comment: @MarineBergot I've answered in the comments of comments

Comment: @M__ thanks for your answer. I arrived in the same point but i need both, latest and refseq. For me latest is working with organism and no partial but refseq is not working even alone. do you have results with Microbacterium[Organism] AND refseq[Filter]? could it be related to version ?

Comment: @MarineBergot its the database. The output of the above search using the nucleotide database is [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=Microbacterium%5BOrganism%5D%20AND%20refseq%5BFilter%5D)